# Specify `nls` restrictions correctly in R

Tags: r, nls

I'm looking to specify start points, as well as upper and lower limits for a `nls()` function. However, I am getting a weird error:

```r
Error in qr(.swts * gr) : 
  dims [product 6] do not match the length of object [100]
In addition: Warning message:
In .swts * gr :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

And here is that error message with `traceback`:

```r
Error in qr(.swts * gr) : 
  dims [product 6] do not match the length of object [100]
In addition: Warning message:
In .swts * gr :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
3: qr(.swts * gr)
2: nlsModel(formula, mf, start, wts, upper, scaleOffset = scOff, 
       nDcentral = nDcntr)
1: nls(formula = y ~ mconst + x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5, data = dat, 
       start = start_vec, lower = lower_vec, upper = upper_vec, 
       algorithm = "port")
```

This is my set-up: I want the variable `mconst` (the intercept) to be restricted to 0 and all others to be estimated flexibly:

```
start_vec <- c(mconst = 0, x1 = 0, x2 = 0, x3 = 0, x4 = 0, x5 = 0)
upper_vec <- c(mconst = 0, x1 = Inf, x2 = Inf, x3 = Inf, x4 = Inf, x5 = Inf)
lower_vec <- c(mconst = 0, x1 = -Inf, x2 = -Inf, x3 = -Inf, x4 = -Inf, x5 = -Inf)

nls(formula =  y ~ mconst + x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5,
    data = dat, 
    start = start_vec, 
    lower = lower_vec,
    upper = upper_vec,
    algorithm = "port")
```

Any ideas?

And here is the data:

```r
dat <- structure(list(y = c(1.13405883740728, 2.84772109915448, 0.193621164365233, 
                            0.557273701772863, 0.266830547845027, 1.32113517775526, 0.6070823722132, 
                            0.453767725018015, 0.0254173670271835, -0.186336707643354, 0.265878603588351, 
                            0.62154829791192, -0.0158733049843671, -0.0952483664384343, 1.97725998455484, 
                            -1.0632139772211, -0.130580843085674, 0.277006116630337, 1.44205445836011, 
                            -1.07448565920205, 0.865024474768183, -0.299896579453989, 2.34663897518307, 
                            0.153347666629399, -0.195093442896394, -0.416517927778444, -0.713876086372485, 
                            1.53342895924156, -0.31421746864901, 0.563362002933162, 1.02441684167773, 
                            1.39503542008671, 1.91220311998148, -0.726469123495154, 0.409633352356755, 
                            -0.965833559346498, -0.166432749743468, -0.627983192341083, -0.296595530569917, 
                            -0.392944150455061, 0.798556278677529, 0.495845802987857, 0.0854202741271615, 
                            -0.403375077255738, 0.00925469774906588, 0.558904982233753, -0.114140744832844, 
                            -0.860867713676224, 1.86553443058753, -0.814367810614249, 0.860235531697781, 
                            0.331937752388764, 0.349745559527548, 0.314121940958195, 1.28801534175686, 
                            0.474380558925254, 1.18908814367116, -1.2554870832364, -1.42103992385108, 
                            1.68007145694179, 0.378927996665909, -0.634559745668991, 0.551681912381438, 
                            1.64186057722607, 0.224135321608078, 0.748846618792702, 0.191039653655259, 
                            1.99100970566853, -0.104634961740907, -0.0191268115696777, 0.157689254180411, 
                            -0.145879966055057, -1.79596167917757, 0.0306452497983381, -0.24103547416707, 
                            1.29472387001398, -1.02308922365488, -0.788067238897557, 0.737815046471602, 
                            0.161158624343516, -1.04885688797489, -1.84845153404132, 0.871103222778003, 
                            -0.835437387634441, -0.874492384643657, -0.344227855331729, 0.233542733233657, 
                            -1.00941674236945, 0.191940498724178, -0.317854306051372, 1.04291598066734, 
                            -0.134960936835448, -0.176675404981001, 1.67832178940783, -0.455357853224243, 
                            -1.14463141509816, 1.65481626532827, -1.53471188993275, 0.428296564189923, 
                            -0.294418864064359), 
                      mconst = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                                 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                                 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                                 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                                 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                                 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
                      x1 = c(0.302633804331088, 0.739905963614184, 
                             1.76535464903255, 0.815681200355033, -0.934293289261378, 0.153845768845634, 
                             -0.996397609338541, 0.10105242396911, 0.542777076003158, 0.0426860943928161, 
                             -0.582632801882351, 0.185608266243935, -0.149995627149592, 0.699331716256751, 
                             0.390115969868581, 0.172329037162217, 0.703063289376068, 0.0510388677104267, 
                             0.457233033513786, 2.25082994224267, 1.1804667384804, -0.299727018348037, 
                             -1.3204579617253, -0.325199105736325, -0.33171332770297, 1.17255814140835, 
                             0.995341459380374, 0.816248373693472, 1.62629991506974, 0.246388974657081, 
                             1.31718291862288, -0.160248971683625, -0.422677252683849, -0.694440755813898, 
                             0.504290444039773, -0.56730221696059, -0.922284221166245, 0.35406281002437, 
                             -0.252656094742627, 0.328403147700528, 1.37737643664807, -0.81950246145071, 
                             0.800054501650381, -0.475024618206999, 1.42925760463557, -0.0193923012164703, 
                             0.311907153719063, -0.352840357129995, -0.308087113949438, 1.03196510662032, 
                             -0.103672278179286, 0.0142676840276278, 0.305753238616465, 1.79471908807313, 
                             -0.966581317093297, 1.02582053390119, 0.610169584538691, 0.451294429149036, 
                             2.6399727436388, 2.14303574184043, 0.820584827805333, -0.105405457842085, 
                             -1.32117882330314, 0.572789292410284, -0.50914790393576, -0.080434323908706, 
                             -0.764767108409075, 0.353015600035983, -0.0999634908822695, 0.359711632338022, 
                             -1.4260874374258, 0.316827880157822, 0.653222990159054, 0.720063288064354, 
                             0.204697138358554, -0.32271933333615, 1.74053386478242, -0.525615951577251, 
                             -0.692973307938779, 0.0295667152726736, -0.690521391414219, 0.392607032836241, 
                             0.75771820784782, 0.117099307887478, -0.100498720976203, -0.698624434447709, 
                             0.151601771967809, -0.852922881052107, 0.861230438062822, 0.117365772795835, 
                             0.967781760461404, -0.678357951503237, 0.42728263706063, 0.283051539548021, 
                             -0.96270130239847, -1.0418953768684, 1.13287795631767, -0.670992215221874, 
                             0.764830793023329, 2.43440398455037), 
                      x2 = c(0.569522129298081, 
                             0.63859179700081, -0.234514821031228, -0.462157483968697, 1.57851188424031, 
                             -0.55501705575703, -0.341954071160875, -1.43930015976029, 1.56337400458932, 
                             0.617058404108507, 1.32961725030378, -0.202797055092979, -0.129650199102789, 
                             0.402951190072858, 1.20149231165233, -0.262623363735354, -0.557964129125097, 
                             -0.605182658436472, -0.825466417225585, 0.14597268384291, 1.54391204564461, 
                             -1.03664690202897, 1.28981851492048, -0.850467210438205, -0.471721513610488, 
                             1.05159636975443, 0.285201901355029, -1.45612157965942, 1.1561880921018, 
                             1.12153262487155, 1.32556247322363, 1.77246531096193, -1.41311523110569, 
                             -0.886378586400302, 0.226547499393422, -0.0307625043931094, 0.971583578914199, 
                             1.12246987616621, 0.0173841128118177, 0.692616274862408, -0.726677934729012, 
                             1.26837973324859, -0.0591632890041252, 0.262576807796542, -0.11472575956593, 
                             1.52493809218105, -1.12513358811654, -0.0516664098123021, 0.206729209563402, 
                             -0.799335566818261, 0.897410301906431, 1.02013396277854, 0.180486557289462, 
                             0.198033565362218, -0.951546091427106, 0.287530623685662, 2.53738715433286, 
                             -1.16460464844296, -0.781592515828818, 0.88374668519681, -0.794070893519112, 
                             2.13902177513349, -0.456470651064564, -0.394923459754832, -0.366793466430605, 
                             0.00418750436084183, 0.0352736620769952, 0.165855273322224, 0.488771518026285, 
                             0.142493273619106, -0.952895931715925, -0.747146549973676, 1.07846924274539, 
                             -1.50571387294225, 0.336717219320933, -1.57361095115542, -1.96988505685846, 
                             0.00571196513082592, 1.11017359451574, 0.422659299958854, 0.887940726497638, 
                             -1.14844697624352, -1.32590298645771, 1.65694035221257, -1.35116566050601, 
                             0.491985932341984, -0.504071916288007, -3.24681554076788, 0.7965879636595, 
                             -0.837704751472094, -0.213279061113036, -1.7146476296281, 0.307917775942152, 
                             2.64114347850664, -0.350407883952232, 1.33386602071975, 0.289284473713601, 
                             -0.855361302297065, 0.276088521600778, -0.797745339705614), 
                      x3 = c(0.714895508755216, 
                             -1.81517338193238, -1.43063716026503, 0.011088243136497, -2.29743630801819, 
                             0.783070679484734, 0.0676467549143852, -0.935722464953065, -0.403782623394446, 
                             -0.229318206040984, -1.15922696536929, -0.328884314376774, -1.58731385768276, 
                             -0.565972923539996, 0.129683743127103, 1.238895467914, -0.601775597109662, 
                             -0.659154878514509, -0.731955349621947, -0.135584838682819, 0.205138266648288, 
                             -1.09635736120029, -0.476114207458552, -0.548389526129234, -0.226948386927217, 
                             0.226809617183294, 3.06329123123167, 1.01201585589112, 0.0445384473588882, 
                             0.877276910317136, 1.49682417838043, -0.257266436646449, 0.651398599528013, 
                             1.79671097472758, 0.851340498577326, 0.445503046639703, 1.35484225101574, 
                             0.770426563506652, -0.903284672036903, -1.99802159264114, 0.320747034816636, 
                             -0.715265512559036, 0.118712746648712, -1.79288423030186, 0.258528482557429, 
                             -0.328736629252367, -0.713165771836817, 1.97612417918516, -0.933950920188644, 
                             0.909367825868753, 0.263958594417371, 1.636778180764, 0.397379508873571, 
                             -1.00679975874749, 0.287720308877587, 0.125497884229027, -0.938420271551775, 
                             0.643115587828679, 0.345920772173288, -0.222372004752682, -0.206038771541888, 
                             -1.32955669316544, 0.983664125010757, -0.424337485962837, -0.153403563875427, 
                             1.89245508512493, 0.261707198395188, 0.736084308221393, -0.302698766208864, 
                             0.982473485184341, 0.0278012773551005, -1.23611436011553, 0.0222068092049307, 
                             -0.433150807561883, 0.62351660899041, 0.24825412614957, 0.652504318163745, 
                             -1.82276551205648, 0.310285184628628, -1.20999886221889, -0.26697517414894, 
                             1.42728812236057, -0.27841223267899, 1.25970944219243, -0.939995352559276, 
                             -1.57914277592484, 0.603459247998757, 0.74948723727518, 0.638130536446766, 
                             -2.05443976081126, -0.479048255527031, -1.28834947380161, -0.190158355219283, 
                             -0.342630558372379, -1.11359890264254, 0.850883303437375, 0.657151112244663, 
                             -1.26238614960628, -0.469208336290708, -0.00497503083261309), 
                      x4 = c(0.173739258524176, -0.135560957300655, -0.0298549952791221, 
                             1.27658669466299, -2.0633510762346, -2.0810183786517, -1.99421250715096, 
                             2.29802697750699, 0.601172134144591, -0.160397602011182, 
                             -0.475671138965258, -0.0256510040837224, -0.250020218704815, 
                             0.760695908851764, 0.161215333111297, 1.96832371711018, -1.1429852215142, 
                             0.189824623393972, -0.258526279218404, 1.49283807420056, 
                             -0.327125056425377, 1.35822019948906, -0.437188397534147, 
                             0.113025207791539, 1.17950727204184, 1.08838892222361, -0.227567285727807, 
                             0.397291930506588, -1.14105461706703, -0.555908705226645, 
                             -0.0240581765873978, 1.00020718927938, 0.0208228892984047, 
                             0.239312119693156, 0.0494710835085402, -0.778797245355919, 
                             -1.80769310297755, 0.354969043336332, 0.287463671665335, 
                             0.109928349940952, -0.434803103860559, -0.920660570685905, 
                             -0.0137176549850479, -0.814231971669972, 0.920314503614708, 
                             1.37648235978706, -0.297080764026484, -0.163770551278264, 
                             0.55635538992842, -0.385672789334636, 0.49760276774036, 0.136119394864841, 
                             -2.40039410615519, -1.12599528730482, 1.10226653445166, -1.69714380888422, 
                             -0.247486989315274, 0.675971862546709, -0.515611991801857, 
                             0.83518091029799, -1.26556745644265, -1.25718729599858, -0.711877170219542, 
                             -1.22048481924645, -1.32455575973636, -0.581467787428742, 
                             -0.552417215147264, -1.77895964004113, 1.30646297787424, 
                             -1.08324764348146, 0.775319236240853, -0.954741577992808, 
                             -0.174459116756985, 0.0234763289614011, -0.489782408636763, 
                             0.511386557888068, 1.24979799166634, -0.484743971433418, 
                             0.073918519419066, 0.110393779140653, -0.339514275023739, 
                             0.807867364903491, -0.22001838896825, 0.119491689708765, 
                             0.672564264441176, -0.191990284011978, -0.826837952044812, 
                             0.346394082958863, -0.657171491907348, -0.255586723156747, 
                             0.452048896647977, 0.52011117424325, -1.2634124232525, 1.47996581491899, 
                             0.367935544991145, -0.0354956491773918, 0.00495149632302872, 
                             -0.729618457953616, 0.478282462548983, 1.64833515263917), 
                      x5 = c(0.533509547713824, -1.45623758053355, -0.133393592532363, 
                             -0.975260782505152, -0.39089346861581, -0.144240057505498, 
                             0.931250599887842, 0.436573839710775, 0.755282393302546, 
                             0.0343238273280755, 2.39361803586658, -0.769400154097157, 
                             -1.98968893282412, -0.477872990998513, 1.89605118194922, 
                             -1.87653981781315, 0.391802231161778, 0.866260035661826, 
                             0.469914918855026, 0.193836038743317, 0.307527644916419, 
                             0.0829662460947629, -0.822720167753068, 0.718051735933974, 
                             -2.34520207596909, -1.62300423015129, 1.52490722233519, -0.0934704498732152, 
                             0.430605216874419, -0.328138026174451, 0.237301553463661, 
                             0.10224606281207, 0.23253675103495, -0.212759537278395, -0.54924491629054, 
                             0.0520732057911415, -0.158880267875488, 0.115807800005446, 
                             0.531209259056011, 0.16685675461598, -0.682127863213933, 
                             -0.406720417779375, -0.896675298060021, -0.914168088131374, 
                             0.268322029657307, -1.79086536713908, -0.365291854033215, 
                             -0.289778638517671, -2.2774068491067, 1.29975233663074, -0.232973943412553, 
                             0.20202102535032, -0.0101062971768026, 0.904101193302026, 
                             -2.22882222079531, -1.61870358096346, -0.135679499625648, 
                             0.770087342651797, 0.0311721877119944, 0.52260009505553, 
                             -0.108272661508776, -0.334263327907715, -0.742547337345534, 
                             -1.08163526580162, 1.37827961030781, 1.79749891977852, -0.83847716289198, 
                             2.45843083566964, -0.43545802725659, -0.157924930088149, 
                             0.193731253206274, 0.887848611876419, 1.79628082815866, 1.33348641619838, 
                             1.37887659619687, 0.505478473511109, -0.372265424038105, 
                             0.902361992503629, 0.691277418232695, 0.155842166186768, 
                             -0.433995936263353, 1.26394450969064, 0.428730577924344, 
                             -0.973767988508749, -0.154595514493372, 0.876985911827588, 
                             1.74153424507417, 0.193984007146465, -0.204207691841853, 
                             0.19099803809888, 0.840396327823894, -1.02016223104357, -1.97249769977284, 
                             -0.500141355715756, 0.722131751024326, 0.509525739142909, 
                             0.896660938761428, 2.2934264960235, 0.196566611181488, -2.84882332200531
                      )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -100L))
```

Comment: Can you change the value of `upper_vec` for the intercept to a very large number instead of `0`, like `1e+10`. This will allow the intercept to vary within a very large range, thus making it unbounded. Try and see what you get. `upper_vec <- c(mconst = 1e+10, x1 = Inf, x2 = Inf, x3 = Inf, x4 = Inf, x5 = Inf)`

Comment: Please run this again and then type `traceback()` to get some info on what threw this error.

Comment: First things first:  plot your data to see what the curve looks like -  I wouldn't be surprised to see one or more of your `x_j` inputs having little or no effect, possibly leading to a precision-limited failure causing that error.

Comment: Thanks all!! Carl, the data is simply simulated from random values (i.e. `rnorm(100)`). So this is more about a general case than about this particular case. And Manoj, I want the intercept to be forced to 0 - so that is the only one that I want not to be unbounded. All others should be unbounded.

Comment: Also thanks, `traceback` output added above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula is incorrect.  mconst and x1 to x5 are variable's values, you need to solve for the coefficients to variables. The model you need to fit is:

y ~ c1 * mconst + c2 * x1 + c3 * x2 + c4 * x3 + c5 * x4 + c6 * x5

Where c1 to c6 are the unknowns.

Try this model instead:

```
start_vec <- c(c1 = 0, c2 = 0, c3 = 0, c4 = 0, c5 = 0, c6 = 0)
upper_vec <- c(c1 = 0, c2 = Inf, c3 = Inf, c4 = Inf, c5 = Inf, c6 = Inf)
lower_vec <- c(c1 = 0, c2 = -Inf, c3 = -Inf, c4 = -Inf, c5 = -Inf, c6 = -Inf)

nls(formula =  y ~ c1*mconst + c2*x1 + c3*x2 + c4*x3 + c5*x4 + c6*x5,
    data = dat, 
    start = start_vec, 
    lower = lower_vec,
    upper = upper_vec,
    algorithm = "port")
```

If you are not interested in having an intercept term, then just leave it out of the `nls()` formula:

```
model <-nls(formula =  y ~  c2*x1 + c3*x2 + c4*x3 + c5*x4 + c6*x5,
            data = dat, 
            start = c(c2 = 0, c3 = 0, c4 = 0, c5 = 0, c6 = 0), 
            algorithm = "port")
summary(model)
```